# Icon along text

Tags: html, css

I got icons and I got text next to it. When I make the screen smaller to around 431px it puts the word underneath the logo [see the upper section called flexibel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4lCe.png) how can I align it that the text stays next to my logo?

Take a look at [bastiaanbos.ch](http://bastiaanbos.ch) for the website itself and the code.

Comment: add some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways to achieve this.

1) You can use a layout framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and harness the grid functionality. For example:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">The icon</div>
<div class="col-md-10">The text</div>
</div>
```

2) You can go a rather "hacky" way and use `html tables`.

3) Worst case scenario: Apply `height` to the first `div`.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the image and text in a div and then change the size of the div with the image based on the height of the text div

```
var heights = $("section").map(function ()
    {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    function check() {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("col-lg-4");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.minHeight=maxHeight + 'px';
    }
}
```

With this method you can have more columns on the side of the image and image will be at the same height as the tallest div .